# How to Disable JavaScript in WebDriver when automating in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently trying to write a test that tests the non-JS version of my website. I use Selenium with Java. I have tried this:

```
 FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
 profile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
 driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
 driver.get();
```

However this isn't working. It just loads the page with JavaScript Enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I did, this, for the requirement.
It will manually set the `javascript.enabled` property to `false` by the following script.

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("about:config");
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).sendKeys("javascript.enabled").perform();
    act.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();
```

Comment: Everything is theoretically impossible, until it is done

Comment: Sure! Will give it a shot today