# Temporarily Block Page from Refreshing via Ajax / Javascript in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using `Selenium` to scrape a webpage. Initially, when you navigate to the web page, the page contains about 10 items. As you scroll to bottom of the page, the page continuously loads more items (via `AJAX / Javascript`) until page has been fully loaded. Once the page is fully loaded I scrape data from each item in list.

Occasionally, I need to delete an item from the page. This causes the page to completely reload/refresh to it's original state with the initial 10 items - forcing me to repeatedly scroll to end of page which is very time consuming. In other words, if the page has a total of 500 items and I need to delete 50 item at various (and unknown) locations through the list I will need to reload entire list of approx. 500 item 50 times.

Since the page is being reloaded via `ajax / js` I thought I could solve this problem by disabling `Javscript` on this specific page. I was able to accomplish this by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31121895) on stackoverflow. However, it is a catch 22 situation - since once I disable `javascript` the page will no longer load new items when I scroll to the bottom. I need to first load all items on page via `Javascript` and then disable `js` so the page does not automatically refresh itself when an item is deleted.

Initially, I thought I could scroll to end of page (while have `js` is enabled) and then disable `js` once I hit the bottom of page so that as I loop through items on page and delete item, page will not be forced to refresh. However, based on my testing I found that once `js` is enabled before page is loaded it can no longer be disabled before you navigate to a different page.

**My question is:** Is there a way for me to temporarily block (or disable) `Javascript` execution after a page has loaded so that the page is not refreshed (yet still allow me to scroll to end of page via `js`)?

Comment: Just want to check, why can't you scrap all the required items by ignoring the items that are not required.

Comment: @supputuri Basically, the list only allows me to maintain a max number of items. When an item is no longer needed it takes up space in list and I need to remove it to free space for other items..

Comment: It would be same case, if you disable js after page load then the list does not updated though you delete the items. The list should be same with either of the approaches.